# linux ld -Ttext fails to generate executable with correct org

Tags: assembly, kernel, nasm, ld

I am working on a 32 bit protected mode kernel. I am trying to generate code whose text region starts at 0x100000. I issue the following command :=

ld -melf_i386 $(OBJS)-o kernel -Ttext 0x100000

I expect when I examine the resulting 32 bit ELF file that e_entry is at 0x100000.
However, it is not, and that is my question as I am not sure why. The kernel
has a portion of it written in nasm and is being compiled on a 64 bit linux 
with a target of 32bit ELF. The actual e_entry value that is produced by
the above ld command is 0x116D5A. I am wondering if this has to do with some compiler 
option that I need like -fpic or some incompatibility with the nasm generated code or
perhaps there is a bug in ld? Could someone please help. Thanks

It should be noted that giving the -r option to ld above as in :=
ld -r -melf_i386 $(OBJS)-o kernel -Ttext 0x100000

Produces output where e_entry is 0x100000 however, the file is not an executable.
I need it to be an executable.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a linker script? It's better to write your own to override the default linker script, since you want fine control over the output.

Something like this,

```
ENTRY(entry)

SECTIONS
{
    .  = 0x100000;

    .text : {
        *(.text)
    }
    ...
```

The above can be used when MMU is not enabled.

If you have MMU enabled, the following will link your kernel to 0xC0000000 (3GB) while still load it at 0x100000.

```
.  = 0xC0100000;

.text : AT(0x100000) {
    *(.text)
}
```